# Android quiz random questions

Tags: android

How can I randomize the questions that will show with `RadioButton`. I looked in the other posts but the answer didn't work for me.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

public class QuizActivity extends Activity {
    int score = 0;
    int qnum = 1;
    TextView txtQuestion;
    RadioButton rda, rdb, rdc, rdd;
    Button butNext;
    RadioGroup rdgrp;

    String corAnswer = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
        DbHelper db = new DbHelper(this);
        rdgrp = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.questionAndAnswers);
        txtQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        rda = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
        rdb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        rdc = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);
        rdd = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio3);
        butNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


        corAnswer = "";
        onCreateQuestion();
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_quiz, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public void onCreateQuestion() {
        String level = getIntent().getExtras().getString("level");
        DbHelper db = new DbHelper(this);
        db.getQuestByLevel(level, qnum);

        txtQuestion.setText(db.question);
        rda.setText(db.optionA);
        rdb.setText(db.optionB);
        rdc.setText(db.optionC);
        rdd.setText(db.optionD);
        corAnswer = db.answer;

        qnum++;

    }

    public void onClickNext(View view) {
        String level = getIntent().getExtras().getString("level");
        DbHelper db = new DbHelper(this);
        db.getQuestByLevel(level, qnum);

        RadioGroup grp = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.questionAndAnswers);
        RadioButton answer = (RadioButton) findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        if (answer == null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "select an answer please", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            return;
        }
        if (corAnswer!= null && corAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase((String) answer.getText()))
        {
            score++;
            Log.d("answer", "Your score" + score);
        }
        if (qnum <= 5) {


        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("score", score);
            intent.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        txtQuestion.setText(db.question);
        rda.setText(db.optionA);
        rdb.setText(db.optionB);
        rdc.setText(db.optionC);
        rdd.setText(db.optionD);
        corAnswer = db.answer;
        qnum++;
        rdgrp.clearCheck();
    }


}
```

Comment: What is your specific problem? What posts did you look at and what did not work?

Comment: there is no problem here. i just need to show random questions

Comment: @Cyril if there is no problem then there is no question

Comment: @BlakeYarbrough im sorry i didnt make it clear . i mean in the codes that I posted there is no error there. my question is how i show the questions random

Answer (score 3):

Place your questions in an `Array` then shuffle this array with:

```
List<String> myArray = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(questionArray));
Collections.shuffle(myArray);
```

Or directly with your SQL query you can use:

```
... ORDER BY RANDOM()...
```

As you can see here, I've got a simple table *[cyril_test]* like this:

[image]

Then I execute the query with the ORDER BY RANDOM():

[image]

And the result is:

[image]

Comment: my questions are in the database . is there any way that i can shuffle them without getting them in a array? sorry im just new in coding

Comment: Good suggestion. Didn't cross my mind about SQL query. +1

Comment: @NicolasCortell can you take a look at my query ? I dont know where to put order by random

Comment: @Cyril I give you an example:  "SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1". Now try to adapt it to your query.

Comment: @NicolasCortell but this is how my query looks
 String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_QUIZ + " WHERE " + q_level  +" = '" + level + "' AND "+QuestionNumber+" = "+qnum+"";

Comment: Ok, so as you can see the one I've posted in example is really similar to yours. I just don't have a WHERE clause but it's really similar. So for your query, if you want to randomize the results you have to add the ORDER BY clause at the end of your query : selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_QUIZ + " WHERE " + q_level +" = '" + level + "' AND "+QuestionNumber+" = "+qnum+" **ORDER BY ...**";

Comment: @Cyril, Is it ok for you now?

Comment: @NicolasCortell no it didnt =(
i put 
selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_QUIZ + " WHERE " + q_level +" = '" + level + "' AND "+QuestionNumber+" = "+qnum+" ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1; 
still not working

Comment: @Cyril, you were not so far... I give you the query: selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_QUIZ + " WHERE " + q_level +" = '" + level + "' AND "+QuestionNumber+" = "+qnum+" ORDER BY RANDOM() " If you set the LIMIT to 1 it will only give you 1 row but that's not what you want

Comment: @NicolasCortell ok so I put - "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_QUIZ + " WHERE " + q_level +" = '" + level + "' AND "+QuestionNumber+" = "+qnum+" ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5"; still it didnt give me random question

Comment: @NicolasCortell yeah i get what you're saying, but when i try it in the app the questions is not random